# Samsung Dishwasher is not spraying

Tags: dishwasher, pump

I have a Samsung DW80K5050US its not that old and under used.

- The water flows in from the side to the base
- The water gets hot
- **The water Won't Spray or move or jet or anything**
- Then the water gets drained out

Any thoughts?  I feel like this should be easy.

Thanks,
-Greg

Comment: Check the circuit and connections for the circulation pump.

Comment: hmm I was starting to think Circulation pump, but I didn't think of the circuit too, you wouldn't happen to be able to point out where on the PCB that is?

Comment: Also I was looking into cheap pumps, and they seem to be related to the Capacitor.  Any idea of how frequently the Capacitor goes bad?

Comment: Do you have a diagram of the PCB?  I found the circulating pump on a parts site but they didn't have any manuals or circuitry. By checking the circuit I meant a volt meter across the pump connections to see it it has voltage.